# Should I create a custom exception type so my code is easier to unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception

In my unit test, I test a method for an expected RuntimeException and I want to distinct those thrown by my component from ones thrown by the code called in the method.

Creating a custom exception type is unnecessary and does not solve the problem if the method throws the same exception type but for different reasons, e.g. InvalidArgumentException.

Looks like the only way to tell them is the message or the error code. Because the message can be changed during development, the error code seems the only reliable option.

What is the best practice for creating of system of error codes so they don't conflict with ones of external packages, eg. third party libraries?

Comment: I have a specific case, where I have to tell apart exceptions of the same type, so I'm wondering if there is a system of best practices or meaningful and safe numbering of error codes.

Answer (score 1):

> Creating a custom exception type is unnecessary and does not solve the
>   problem if the method throws the same exception type but for different
>   reasons, e.g. InvalidArgumentException.

Why do you think it's unnecessary? This is what you should do. Derive your own custom exception classes, throw their instances from your code and catch them outside (in your unit tests). The `catch` statement can be repeated in anticipation of multiple different exception classes:

```
try {
    // something
} catch (MySpecificException e) {
    // you know that your code threw this
} catch (Exception e) {
    // this is coming from somewhere else
}
```

Comment: Subclassing MyInvalidArgumetException from InvalidArgumentException does not give the test a clue which argumet is invalid.

Comment: @user42882: The idea is that you can have properties that specify this information. Error codes are not the way to proceed, here.

Comment: @user42882 You wouldn't inherit from InvalidArgumentException of course. That exception already has a sufficiently specific meaning. You could instead derive a InvalidPortNumber etc. exception if you need specificity at that level.

Comment: You'll end up with a custom exception class for each check, eg.
NotExactly64CharsInvalidArgumentException, IntNotIn1000_1200RangeInvalidArgumentException. A clear message and a simple InvalidArgumentException would be sufficient for a developer, but what about unit tests?

Comment: @user42882 You'd obviously not take it that far with defining specific, custom exceptions. What's sufficient/necessary for the user and for a unit test are slightly different. You would want to include human-readable textual messages along with your exceptions (so that they are logged, displayed to the user etc.), but your unit tests should only care about the exception class that is being thrown. Don't make your unit tests rely on parsing of text messages that are intended for humans.

Comment: The exception error code is for distinguishing between exceptions of the SAME type while the catch sorts out exceptions of DIFFERENT types. Quite different roles, eh?

Comment: @user42882 Correct. The trick is to make the smart decisions between using different exception classes versus using a common classe with different property settings. It only comes with experience through trial and error. You shouldn't expect to find a recipe on this...

Comment: I have a specific case, where I have to tell apart exceptions of the same type, so I'm wondering if there is a system or best practices of meaningful and safe numbering of error codes.

Answer (score 0):

--Edit--

Sorry, I didn't see the java tag. Even though the following example uses PHP constructs, the principles should still apply.

--Original--

I use custom exception codes in only a few, very specific cases, and I store these codes in a custom exception class which extends the default exception class. They are stored in the class as constants, as the value doesn't really matter, but the context does.

Consider:

```
class CoreLib_Api_Exception extends Exception
{
    const EXCEPTION_FORMAT = '%s (%s): %s';

    const CODE_FILE_DNE                 = 100;
    const CODE_DIR_BASE_EQUALS_REMOVE   = 101;

    const CODE_XML_READER_UNABLE_TO_OPEN = 200;
    const CODE_XML_READER_UNABLE_TO_READ = 201;
}

// Example usage
class CoreLib_Api_Reader
{
    protected function getReader()
    {
        $reader = new CoreLib_Api_Xml_Reader();

        if (!@$reader->open($this->getFileUri())) {

            $e = new CoreLib_Api_Exception(sprintf('Could not open %s for parsing', $this->getFileUri()), CoreLib_Api_Exception::CODE_XML_READER_UNABLE_TO_OPEN);

            throw $e;
        }
    }
}

// Calling  code
try {

    $reader = CoreLib_Api_Reader();

    $reader->setFileUri($fileUri);
    $reader->getReader();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    // If code is anything other than open, throw it
    if ($e->getCode() !== CoreLib_Api_Exception::CODE_XML_READER_UNABLE_TO_OPEN) {
        throw $e;
    }

    $e = null;

    $reader = null;
}
```

By using the exception code, I can check to determine if the reader is unable to open the file, if so ignore the exception and move on, otherwise throw the exception and break the flow.

And if one of my exception codes collides with a third party exception code, it doesn't matter, as I mentioned before, using constants, the context will dictate which code I want to match on.

Comment: Using class constants was my initial impulse to avoid magic numbers and tie the constants to the context. But again, I'd rather use standard exception types, as they suitable for most cases.

Comment: Ya, various exception types will work as well. For some reason I don't care for them. Having to check for 7 different exception types every-time I make an API call seems redundant to me. I'd rather just have the exception, and test for a 'pin-holed' exception code, if it matches, then continue on.

Comment: Never heard of this being done before. This may work when setting the code, but how you would check the code?

Comment: A PHP example: throw new \InvalidArgumetException('The server returned bad response: ' . $responseStr, errHash('bad-server-response'));. In the catch: if(errHash('bad-server-response') == $e->getCode()) { handle it here ... }

Comment: Interesting. That has some definite flexibility, however it suffers from what all variables like this suffer, if you want to rename 'bad-server-response' to something else, you will have to change every code-point. If you used class constants you could change the value to whatever you like without having to update code.

Comment: Agree. Class constants looks like a more elegant solution but you'll end up with a custom exception class for each task in the code.

Comment: If you let it. As I mentioned earlier, I only setup important codes to 'pinhole' my catches, otherwise you end up with a laundry list of codes. I've been able to get by with only 4 exception codes across hundres of classes and thousands lines of code, so it is possible to implement strict boundaries, but I digress, what works for me, may not work for you.

Answer (score -1):

> I test a method for an expected RuntimeException

I think this is a mistake. A `RuntimeException` should be used only for indicating bugs in the code that the code itself can detect. Testing should test only for specified (defined) behaviour. But when there is a bug in some code, its behaviour is undefined (who knows where the bug could be or what it might do). So there is  no point in trying to specify what `RuntimeException`s some code should throw; that is like specifying how the code should behave "in the presence of a bug". Throwing particular `RuntimeException`s with particular messages should be seen as a courtesy to the maintenance programmer (who is likely to be you).

Comment: This is not true.  Exceptions are not necessarily caused by bugs.  Throwing an exception might be part of the contract of the unit under test.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "Throwing an exception might be part of the contract": I assert that only *checked* exceptions are part of the contract. The contract will also provide preconditions that the *caller* must satisfy. Failure to satisfy a precondition should ideally result in a suitable, informative `RuntimeException` being thrown, but the contract should not *specify* what that is. Or even that it will certainly occur.

Comment: @Raedwald assert all you want. That doesn't mean that everyone else agrees.